# Stretch game across multiple monitors in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, amd-radeon, gaming

I've got three monitors next to one another in portrait mode, so my full resolution is 3240x1920.

I'd like to have the game stretch over all three monitors, so they behave as a single large-resolution monitor.

Additional information:

- Windows 7
- AMD Radeon HD 7790
- side monitors use DVI, middle one uses DisplayPort (can't have any other combination, tricky connector situation)

Comment: Check out [Widescreen Gaming](http://www.wsgf.org/). I've used tools from them in the past to force better widescreen resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [AMD radeon based card](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/7000/7700#) installed. These support something which AMD calls **[Eyefinity](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/MultimonitorFAQ.aspx)**.

If you enable that then windows will treat all three of your screens as one single large display. Maximising windows will spread out over all three displays. The taskbar will be across all three displays. **Games which open full screen should open across all three displays**.

Note that performance at 3240x1920 will be less than on a single 1080x1920 screen.

---

Assuming you did not want Eyefinity all the time:

It should be possible to create two profiles in CCC. One with Eyefinity, one without. then either:

1. Switch between profiles with the CCC's hotkeys just before launching the game.
2. Or create a batch-file which does the following:
   1) Switch profile enabling eyefinity.
   2) Wait a few seconds for this to happen before launching the game.
   3) start the game
   4) (Optional) Cleanup to normal mode after the game exits.

I have not personally tried any of these yet (though I might if/when I ever get a third monitor).

Comment: is it possible to do this *only* in games, though? Not a pressing issue since I only use Windows for gaming, but it'd be nice.

Comment: Expanded the answer. Deleted old (and now irrelevant) comments.